# Is it possible to get Qpoint from QModelIndex

Tags: c++, qt

Is it possible to get a Qpoint from a QModelIndex. I would like to get a Qpoint so that I could display a tooltip at a certain row.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `QAbstractItemView::visualRect(const QModelIndex &index)` that will return the rectangle on the viewport occupied by the item at index.
For example:

```
QRect rect = tableView->visualRect(index); // index is a QModelIndex
QPoint pos = tableView->mapToGlobal(rect.center());
QToolTip::showText(pos, "This is my tool tip", tableView, rect);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should implement your model so that it returns tooltip contents when `Qt::ToolTipRole` role is requested. This is a proper model-view way to add tooltips to views.